# Angular ui router reload ajax data when back button is clicked

Tags: angularjs

Angular using ui router

If I load data from the srv with ajax, click on a link that change the state, and then go back to the previous link/state (by clicking back or a link) then the ajax data is lost from the $scope.

What is the correct way to store the data and avoid re running the ajax call?

Comment: run the jax call but [use cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching)

Comment: your data should be in a service, keep it and only reload it if is time sensitive data.